# Debug to find onscroll not working between production and development site

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, debugging

I'm kind of stuck on a onscroll-event. On my development site ([enter link description here](https://develop.uisge-beatha.eu)) the onscroll is working: a button to return to the top appears, de header color changes and the logo on the top right resizes. The same use case on the production site ([enter link description here](https://uisge-beatha.eu)) shows the scroll to top button in the right corner, and the header color changes, however the logo doesn't shrink. The production site is a copy of the development site. The framework is based on Bootstrap 4.3.1

The scroll behaviour is done via javascript dyscrollup.js. A snippet showing the scroll behaviour:

```
onscroll: function () {
    var self = this, btn = document.getElementById(self.btnID);
    var Logo = document.getElementById("header_logo"); // logo
    window.onscroll = function () {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > self.option.showafter || document.documentElement.scrollTop > self.option.showafter) {
            // Show the button if not yet visible
            if (btn.style.display === 'none') {
                self.fadeIn(btn);
            }
            Logo.className = 'smallLogo'; // resize logo 2 small 
            // If page is not scrolling back to the top after clicking
            // the dyscrollup-btn then remove the click lock
            if (!btn.classList.contains('dyscrollup-btn-scrolling')) {
                btn.classList.remove('click-locked');
            }
        }
        else {
            // Hide the button when approaching the top
            if (btn.style.display !== 'none') {
                self.fadeOut(btn);
            }
            // Remove the click lock
            btn.classList.remove('click-locked');
            Logo.className = 'largeLogo'; // resize logo 2 large
        }
    };
},
```

The css snippet for resizing the logo:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  #header_logo {
    transition: all .5s;
    }
      .largeLogo { 
        width: 130px;
        max-height: 8vh;
      }
      .smallLogo  {
          width: 6.125rem;
          height: 4vh;
      }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  /* For larger phones and screens: */
  #header_logo {
    transition: all .5s;
    }
      .largeLogo {
        width: 260px;
        max-height: 18vh;
      }
      .smallLogo  {
          width: 12.125rem;
          height: 6vh;
      }
}
```

A different browser doesn't make any difference in the behaviour between the two sites. Been staring at the debug window, however that doesn't help me any further, it doesn't show me an error or warning that is of any help.

What steps can/should I take to further debug the site in order to find the root cause?

Comment: It's working fine for me on both develop and prod, background changes and logo shrinks.

Comment: Thanks @SanJarral. Good to hear! Bit strange though. Cleared caches etc. but the difference remains, even on my mobile.

Comment: Yeah same here, seems to work just fine. Tested with Chrome and FF

Comment: make sure to refresh browser with SHIFT+refresh button in order to bypass cached assets (css/javascript/images) and reload from start

Comment: Also, are you using CDN? If you are, maybe you didn't clear the CDN's cache properly.

Comment: Clearing the CDN cache did do the trick. Thanks @RaduDiță